# Segfault with GLFW and GLEW

Tags: c, opengl, segmentation-fault, glew, glfw

I have the following code, taken from part of an OpenGL application I'm working on. GDB reports that the code segfaults immediately when calling `glfwInit()`. The strange thing is, if I change the value of `height` to 256 (or at least, anything so `height` < 512), the segfault disappears.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

static const size_t width = 512;
static const size_t height = 512;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwOpenWindow(1080, 720, 8, 8, 8, 0, 32, 0, GLFW_WINDOW);
    glewInit();

    float heightmap[width * height * 3];
    for (size_t i = 0, ix = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            float noise = 0.0f;
            heightmap[ix++] = (float)i;
            heightmap[ix++] = noise;
            heightmap[ix++] = (float)j;
        }
    }

    const int numIndices = (width - 1) * (height - 1) * 6;timd
    GLuint indices[numIndices];
    for (size_t i = 0, ix = 0; i < width - 1; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < height - 1; j++) {
            indices[ix++] = (i + 0) + (j + 0) * width;
            indices[ix++] = (i + 1) + (j + 0) * width;
            indices[ix++] = (i + 0) + (j + 1) * width;
            indices[ix++] = (i + 0) + (j + 1) * width;
            indices[ix++] = (i + 1) + (j + 0) * width;
            indices[ix++] = (i + 1) + (j + 1) * width;
        }
    }

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, width * height * 3 * sizeof(float), heightmap, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, numIndices * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    do {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        glfwSwapBuffers();
    } while(glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) != GLFW_PRESS);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);

    glfwCloseWindow();
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

the backtrace from GDB shows

```
#0  0x00000000004009d7 in main (argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff6fe41c>, argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff6fe410>) at segfault.c:8
```

I'm compiling with `gcc -g -o segfault segfault.c -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw`.

I'm stumped as to what is causing this error, I don't understand why changing the value of `height` affects the segfault.

EDIT: posted more code. segfault still occurs with width/height at 512 but runs fine at 256.

Comment: Well, `512 * 512 * 3`, multiplied again by 3 for 4 bytes per float, gives you 3145728 bytes. Or 3.14 MB (PI?!). This is also only ONE array, and you're also making another indices array later. Are you sure you aren't absolutely obliterating your stack and possibly the heap? Ie, try dynamically allocating these arrays on the heap instead. Should be a tad safer. Oh, maybe check what GCC's standard stack size is (I don't use GCC, so I can't help much there)? I could be totally off in thinking stack/heap corruption is an issue.

Comment: `by 4 for 4 bytes per float`* Totally forgot to fix that.

Comment: @Hydronium: I had made a mistake in my call to `glBufferData()`, but your suggestion to allocate on the heap solved my problem. Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You end up allocating 9437184 bytes of data on the stack. *9.43 MB*. This is *a lot* of memory in one stack frame, and possibly more than your environment allows for the entire stack.

To be honest I'm not sure what the *precise* issue is, but since you mention a smaller height value fixes everything (cutting height in half gives ~4.7 MB) I think this is the issue. At least, 5MB seems sorta reasonable for stack size though I've read [the default for Visual Studio is 1MB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If you want to go deeper into this, discover what the default stack size GCC gives or explicitly set the stack size (assuming you can) until you find a segfault. A quick search says it's around [8MB](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/default-stack-size-on-linux-glibc-pthreads-358438/), though this may not be accurate for you. Assuming this is correct then you managed to exceed it.

Set that data on the heap dynamically. It's normally meant for large amounts of data, while the stack is meant for temporary/local storage.

Comment: I invite anyone with more knowledge of the relationships between the stack, heap, and GCC, to expand on this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize `heightmap` with data:

```
float heightmap[width * height * 3];
/* ... */
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(heightmap), heightmap, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

If all what you want to do is initializing the OpenGL Buffer Object, you can simply pass a null pointer.

BTW: All the `glBuffer…` have been core ever since OpenGL-1.4, i.e. you should not use the `ARB` extensions but can use the core functions safely, even on the oldest implementations you'll find these days (it even works for my old GeForce2 based antique computers).